# Undo an accidental hg strip?

Tags: mercurial, undo, revert

I have accidentally run hg strip, and deleted a stack of commits. I have not done anything in the repo since. Is there a way for me to bring back this stack of commits, to undo the hg strip I just ran?

Answer (score 31):

As long as you didn't run the strip with the `--no-backup` option, the stripped changesets can be found in the repository under `.hg\strip-backup`.  If you sort the directory content by date the latest one is likely the one you need to restore.  Restore it with `hg unbundle <filename>`.

Comment: I heart you.  That bit of info saved hours of redoing work.

Comment: Wow! You save me for a second time! Can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a worked example of `unbundle` [from an external post](https://community.nexj.com/2016/04/11/recovering-stripped-files-using-mercurial/). I've cleaned it up slightly to make it a little more general:

> **Recovering stripped files when using Mercurial**
>
> If you accidentally strip a patch and do not have a backup for it, you
>   can still recover your files using Mercurial. To recover your files:
>
> Open a Microsoft Windows Command Prompt window.
>
> Navigate to the project folder where you stripped the files.
>
> Run the `dir` command
>
> Navigate to the `.hg` folder where Mercurial stores all relevant project
>   files.
>
> Run the `dir` command again.
>
> Navigate to the strip-backup folder where Mercurial stores the backup
>   bundles of stripped patches.
>
> Run the `dir` command again. Multiple files display in the directory
>   that use the `<hash>-hg` format. They are the backup bundles of stripped
>   patches.
>
> [image]
>
> Use Windows Explorer to find the required file. Open the `strip-backup`
>   folder in Windows Explorer, and sort by Date modified descending.
>   Unless the necessary backup bundle is already known, [it is recommended to]
>   restore the bundles in reverse chronological order starting
>   from the most recent bundle.
>
> [image]
>
> Navigate back to the project folder.
>
> To restore a bundle, run `hg unbundle .hg\strip-backup\<bundle_file_name>`. ... You may want to add it to the
>   `PATH` environment variable to make it accessible globally.
>
> [image]
>
> Synchronize the project [using `hg pull`] to see the restored patch. If
>   the restored patch is not the one needed, then continue restoring the
>   patches in reverse chronological order until the required patch is
>   retrieved.
>
> Note: You may restore the backup bundles in any order, instead of
>   using reverse chronological order. However, it may not be safe to do
>   so. You may end up attempting to restore a backup bundle, which has a
>   dependency on another backup bundle that has not been restored. In
>   this case, you will get an error.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to `hg pull` from a strip backup file as an alternative to using `hg unbundle`.

As noted in a comment on another answer to this question,  *`hg unbundle` has fewer options and only works with bundles, but can unbundle more than one bundle at a time. Whereas `hg pull` can pull from a single source (share/web/bundle) and has other options*.

Here's an example of using `hg pull` based on [an external post](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2011-July/039016.html) by Isaac Jurado:

> Usually the backup is placed in `REPO/.hg/strip-backup/`. See the
>   example below:
>
> ```
>  $ hg glog
>  @  changeset:   2:d9f98bd00d5b tip
>  |               three
>  o  changeset:   1:e1634a4bde50
>  |               two
>  o  changeset:   0:eb14457d75fa
>                  one
>  $ hg strip 1
>  1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
>
>  saved backup bundle to
>  /Users/hchapman/ttt/.hg/strip-backup/e1634a4bde50-backup.hg
> ```
>
> And then, what one would do to recover those changesets would be:
>
> ```
> $ hg pull $(hg root)/.hg/strip-backup/e1634a4bde50-backup.hg
> ```