# How to go back to the latest changeset after doing wrong hg strip

Tags: tortoisehg

Our repo has a main repo and a subrepo. Yesterday I wanted to delete my local commits. So I useD `hg strip #changeset# --keep`.

The mistake that I made is that the draft that I want to delete is in subrepo. But I didn't come to the right directory to proceed the command. The changeset that I deleted is in the main repo.

So in workbench of tortoise hg, I came back to a very very old revision of main repo. Subrepo disappeared (though in my working copy they are still there).

And I cannot update to the latest revision , `hg update` failed. Let me call my subrepo A. The error reports `"A.\xxrc" is in the nested repo A"`. So I have no idea what to do now.

Comment: Because of your subrepo I'm not 100% certain if this is a normal case of "undoing" a strip... but try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274499/undo-an-accidental-hg-strip

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've seen this question before. But I don't have a file named strip-backup under /.hg.