# Pulling a stripped branch?

Tags: mercurial

Using Mercurial I pushed a branch to Kallithea.

Later I deleted the local branch using `hg strip my-branch`.

Is it now possible to pull it from Kallithea?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274499/undo-an-accidental-hg-strip

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since your `strip` operation was local and you had already pushed the changesets you stripped, when you pull they should all be brought back. It should be like you had never run strip.